# fabric Socket exception: Connection timed out

Tags: python, fabric

Sometimes while my fabric script is running which basically runs several commands on remote machines, I encounter this error:

```
ERROR:paramiko.transport:Socket exception: Connection timed out (110)
!!! Parallel execution exception under host 'xyz'
....
....      (several logs here)
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

My code is something like this:

```
with settings(....):
    execute(tasks,...)
```

Is there a way using which fabric can retry the old command instead of skipping over it when it meets such time outs, for example have an option of retry in settings above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Fabric 1.4+, use the `env.connection_attempts` parameter, or a similar flag on the command line.

**`Multiple connection attempts and skipping bad hosts`**

> As of Fabric 1.4,
>   multiple attempts may be made to connect to remote servers before
>   aborting with an error: Fabric will try connecting
>   env.connection_attempts times before giving up, with a timeout of
>   env.timeout seconds each time. (These currently default to 1 try and
>   10 seconds, to match previous behavior, but they may be safely changed
>   to whatever you need.)

from http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#multiple-connection-attempts-and-skipping-bad-hosts